# Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

This is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.initConfig({
uglify:{
my_target: {
files:{
'_/js/script.js': ['_/components/js/*.js']      
}//files
}//myTarget
},//uglify
compass: {
dev:{
options: {
config: 'config.rb',                    
}//options
}//dev
},//compass
watch: {
options: {livereload: true},
scripts: {
files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],
tasks: ['uglify']       
},//scripts     
html: {
files: ['*.html']
},//html
sass: {
files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss']
tasks: ['compass:dev']
},//sass  
}//watch
})//initConfig
grunt.registerTask('default','watch'); 
}//exports
```

Running grunt in Command Prompt gives ERROR:
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

When I comment out SASS block (in gruntfile.js)... then  grunt says: Running "watch" task Waiting ... and everything is working fine!

Does anyone know what could be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me there just seemed to be a few simple typo's, missing `,`'s etc
Also, try register a task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
```

here is a tidied up version, hopefully this works for you.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    '_/js/script.js': ['_/components/js/*.js']
                } //files
            } //myTarget
        }, //uglify
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                } //options
            } //dev
        }, //compass
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            scripts: {
                files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }, //scripts     
            html: {
                files: ['*.html']
            }, //html
            sass: {
                files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            } //sass  
        } //watch
    }); 
    //initConfig
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
} //exports
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion helped ... grunt is Running "Watch" task and Waiting ... but when I change something in styles.scss, and save I get this: Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "_\components\sass\styles.scss" changed.
Warning: Task "compass:dev" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 1.753s at Thu Feb 05 2015 14:27:39 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Tim
e) - Waiting...

Comment: Great, if the answer helped answer your question, you can accept it by clicking the big tick so others know what solution worked. If you are still having a problem, please provide details, thanks

Comment: you are calling `['compass:dev']` in the `watch` task, but you havent loaded the `compass` plugin. you need to install and load the "compass" plugin with: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');` or whatever compass plugin you are using

Comment: That solved the problem ... everything is working as it should!!! Thanx again for your help. And I accepted your answer by clicking the big tick! :) (sorry I didn't do it in the first place, I'm new here)

Comment: glad it worked, I didnt know how the tick and upvote worked when I first started either, thats why I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

My reason is that I download the zip file, and the zip files do not contain the source files, only the built files, so there is no need for grunt tasks. I use `git clone` to clone the source file, solved this issue.